# Why do includes need further dependencies?

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation

My current understanding is like this. Please correct me if I am wrong. When I include a C++ library (e.g. open source project) to my project I have to include the .h files so that the compiler knows about the interface of the included library. The compiled code of the included library is then linked by the linker.

But now during compilation, the included header file needs another dependency. If I would include the header file of this dependency won't this turn into some recursive loop until every dependency is included? Why is it needed? Shouldn't be this the concern of the linker? The compiled library contains the dependency.

I stumbled over this project using Xcode 9.4.

Comment: It might help to think of it like this: Every `#include` statement is equivalent to just copy-pasting the entirety of the included code in the location of the `#include`. So to the linker, a .h file including another is equivalent to just one header containg the definitions of both.

Comment: `#include` part is unrelated to linker stage BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compiler translates code into machine language. The said code is then strung together with other machine code using a linker. Google more on what I wrote, if confused; it is a simplification missing finer details.

When you type `#include <cstdint>` for example, a *preprocessor*, which is another separate program, does a pattern substitution, if you will, on `#include <cstdint>` and replaces that line with the whole contents of the `cstdint.hh` file. The substitute happens before the translation process to machine code even begins.

Usually, these `#include <...>` files are written carefully so that you do not need to chase *other* `#include`. However, that is not a guarantee.

Comment: So the problem I encountered is that the library I included was not written carefully because the header file uses an include to another library?

Comment: actually the opposite; the library is missing that #include file from what I can surmise. i.e. it is trying to use code in some other .hh but does not include it itself and then complains to you about it!

Answer (score 0):

The risk you identify exists. It's not automatic, though. If `a.h` includes `b.h` which includes `c.h`, there is no problem with nested includes.

You could have a problem if `a.h` includes both `b.h` and `c.h`, and `b.h` also includes `c.h` indirectly. The risk here isn't so much recursion, but double-definition of the contents of `c.h`.

The usual solution is that every header starts with

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED
#define A_H_INCLUDED

// actual contents of "a.h"
```

and ends with

```
#endif // A_H_INCLUDED
```

Now, the second inclusion of `c.h` is harmless. When this happens, `C_H_INCLUDED` will be already defined by the first inclusion, so the second inclusion is wholly skipped. Some compilers are smart enough to recognize this pattern and won't even read `c.h` the second time, saving a few milliseconds of disk I/O.

The linker can't solve this, because the double-definition problem happens before the linker is involved. It happens at the level of individual Translation Units. A Translation Unit is basically a single .cpp file after all its .h files have been included. Each TU is handled individually by the compiler, and it's this compiler which trips over the double definitions. The linker cares a bit less about duplications. Duplicate function definitions are a problem for the linker, class definitions are not.